# Finding IP return hex address

Tags: raspbian, ping

In Windows 10 cmd line issuing

> ping raspberrypi.local

to find the IP address of the Raspberry Pi returns a hex address like this:

> fe80::103d:b922:5838:6142%9

How can I get the numerical IP address?

Comment: it is an IPv6 addr not an IPv4 addr, try: `ping -4 -c 1 raspberrypi.local` on Linux and Windows : `ping -4 -n 1 raspberrypi.local`

Comment: Thanks @Ephemeral but issuing above command in win 10 I got: Access denied. Option -c requires administrative privileges.

Comment: Sorry, it's `-n 1` for windows but you can also omit that.. keep only `-4`

Comment: great it is working. :) thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) address, not an [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address. Tell *ping* to search IPv4 only with the `-4` option:

- On Linux: `ping -4 -c 1 raspberrypi.local`
- On Windows: `ping -4 -n 1 raspberrypi.local`